# Error with Script Publishing Service from MXD with UNC Paths

Tags: python, arcmap, arcgis-online

I have script that attempts to publish a service which consists of a single tiff.

I am using boilerplate ESRI code for this one:

```
# initialize
imagery_date = 'some date'
folder_name = 'name of folder'
summary = 'summary info_{}'.format(imagery_date)
service_name = 'name of service_{}'.format(imagery_date)
workspace = r'\\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\Imagery'
ags_con = r'xxxx\xxxx.xxxx.xxxx_6443 (admin)'
service = "{}/{}/{}.MapServer".format(ags_con, folder_name, service_name)
map_doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(workspace, '{}.mxd'.format(service_name)))
sddraft = os.path.join(workspace, '{}.sddraft'.format(service_name))
sd = os.path.join(workspace, '{}.sd'.format(service_name))

analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(map_doc, sddraft, service_name, 'ARCGIS_SERVER',ags_con, False, folder_name, summary, tags)

if analysis['errors'] == {}:
    # Execute StageService
else:
    # if the sddraft analysis contained errors, display them
    print("ERROR!!")
    print(analysis['errors'])
```

The script fails with this error:

`ExecuteError: ERROR 001272: Analyzer errors were encountered (codes = 3).`

This [error](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/map/publish-map-services/00003-layer-s-data-source-is-inaccessible.htm) is supposed to occur when the layers data source is not accessible, and ESRI suggests repairing the broken link.

When I open the MXD I'm publishing from, there are no broken links. When I analyze the service, there are also no errors, and I can publish from the MXD.

The tiff in my MXD is referenced via a UNC path, and I do not have relative paths stored.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before?

Comment: "3" is not the same as Error 0003 as you link too. Your error is 1272: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01251-01275-001272.htm   Change your code to print all of the analysis value, ie:  `print(analysis)` and run again and see if there are other errors.

Comment: Or, that error could be coming from lines you haven't shown us based on the fact you say `ExecuteError`. Perhaps your error is coming from StageService or The UploadTool. Either way, you'll need to provide more script and more printed errors. At this point it _could_ be a UNC issue, or 100 other different things.

Comment: @KHibma isn't error 1272 a generic code stating that errors were encountered, and the code in the parenthesis is the specific value? if '3' is not 0003, then what else could it be?

Comment: @KHibma also, I should note, that error is not being generated by the print statement, but by arcmap, from within the script tool i'm running